# Laravel Eloquent distinct values

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

PROBLEM SOLVED.

I'm trying to get an person's books, but there are more than one book in my book table since there are different editions of a book. When I list all books of a person, I shouldn't list duplicates.

Here's what I've done so far

Person Model

```
public function books() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Thing', 'bookxauthor', 'person_id', 'thing_id');
}
```

PersonController.php

```
$allbooks = Person::find($id)->books;
```

This is great, it lists all the books of an author, but I don't need duplicates.

The query below works. type_id means it's a book.

```
$findBooks = Person::with(array('books' => function($query)
            {
                $query->where('type_id',"=",3)->groupBy('original_name');
            }))->find($id);

            $allbooks = $findBooks->books;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the groupBy function for collections
Eg.

```
$allbooks = Person::find($id)->books->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to add another query (where type_id =3), so I used the callback function thingy.

Comment: Yea great, also check into filter() function for collections in laravel. http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_filter It might be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

The query below works.

```
$findBooks = Person::with(array('books' => function($query)
            {
                $query->where('type_id',"=",3)->groupBy('original_name');
            }))->find($id);

            $allbooks = $findBooks->books;
```