# Unique results from the Laravel database 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have schema:

```
Schema::create('statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('agent')->nullable();
            $table->date('date')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('ip');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('quest_id')->default(0);
            $table->string('browser', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('platform', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('language', 12)->nullable();
//            $table->string('url_address', 160)->nullable();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

I get statistics from this function:

```
public function generateStatistics(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $id)
    {
        return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->where('user_id', $id)->get();
    }
```

This function returns all the results from the database to me and works correctly. I need to redo this function to display unique results. Unique result = unique ip on the selected day.

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416110/laravel-eloquent-distinct-values)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a dictinct ip

```
public function generateStatistics(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $id)
{
    return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->where('user_id', $id)->distinct('ip')->get();
}
```

or you can group by ip

```
public function generateStatistics(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $id)
{
    return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->where('user_id', $id)->groupBy('ip')->get();
}
```

Comment: it's not working. I need UNIQUE visits and TOTAL VISITS. At the moment, unique records are identical to all these

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by unique? get the list of distinct IPs on that range? this would be like this:

```
public function generateStatistics(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $id)
    {
        return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])
                 ->where('user_id', $id)
                 ->select('ip')
                 ->distinct()
                 ->get();
    }
```

EDIT: I saw that the thing you want is not the IPs values just the count for the statistics.

Transforming to MYSQL should be something like this (This maybe helps you to your code):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), ip
FROM statistics
WHERE user_id = {{id}} AND date BETWEEN {{dateFrom}} AND {{dateTo}}
GROUP BY ip;
```

So this will return the number of request grouped by IP. The SUM of all counts will give you the total of request, the count of IPs will give you the total of UNIQUE request.

To Laravel:

```
$requestPerIp = Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])
         ->where('user_id', $id)
         ->select('ip', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
         ->groupBy('ip')
         ->get();
```

For the total unique request just:

```
$numberOfUniqueRequest = count($requestPerIp);
```

Comment: it's return nothing :(

Comment: Just updated the post. check it out, and if you have problems just reply. good luck